# Can SSIS connect to an instance of a C# class to extract data directly?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ssis, etl

I'm a new C# developer so bear with me. I have a class DisplayUserDetails in my desktop application that's created in .NET C# (very basic). It has many methods that display outputs e.g., UserName, UserGeography, UserPreferences, etc. I'm evaluating the option of creating an API to be used internally within the company, or somehow extracting the data using SSIS directly through the Class (no API). Within the .NET code, I would write something like this to create a new instance of the class:

```
private Employee.DisplayUserDetails dUsrDtls
```

Is there a way within SSIS or any other ETL tool to be able to directly connect to the Class to extract the data?

Is there any to do this or may I completely off track here?

Thanks!

Comment: How does SSIS come into this? No SSIS can't extract data out of runtime class unless you expose it somehow (i.e. with an API). But you must be loading data into this class from something else. Once you access the data in your class with SSIS where are you going to put it? What is the purpose of all this?

Comment: Thanks for responding.Actually, what I really need to do is to do real-time manipulation of data and expose it ultimately in a reporting tool i.e., Tableau. To provide more context, I want to give other developers the ability to extract the data for their custom reporting without giving them direct access to the database.

Comment: I suggest you use views or stored procedures for this. SSIS and ETL is not suitable for supplying data to a reporting tool

Answer (score 1):

> I want to give other developers the ability to extract the data for their custom reporting without giving them direct access to the database

You could expose it via a web service, an API, a file dump, etc.  To do it via SSIS, I would write a console program and write to a csv file.

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var myClass = new EmployDetails(args);
        // write to file

        // trigger a tableau refresh service
        // anything, really
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle. That's helpful though I just realized that they will need to extract and then store it in a database somewhere as they will be doing reporting against it (large datasets). So really, it feels the best option is to create an API for it so they can access it. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to expose a database behind an API for use by a reporting tool, the most straightforward and proven way is to use views and store procedures. *or* even easier, only allow connection through a user that has specific security access (for example read only access, doesn't have access to certain tables.

SSIS does not add any value here and is only complicating things.